# Creating a special Toeplitz matrix in R

Tags: matrix, r

I'd like to know if there is a standard way of creating a matrix like the one shown below using the R programming language.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & \rho & \rho^2 & \cdots & \rho^{T-1}\\
        \rho & 1 & \rho & \cdots & \rho^{T-2}\\
        \rho^2 & \rho & 1  & \cdots & \rho^{T-3}\\
        \vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        \rho^{T-1} & \rho^{T-2} & \rho^{T-3} & \cdots & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The code I've been using to create matrices like this one is shown below.

For illustrative purposes, let rho = 0.8 and T = 20.

```
rho <- 0.8
t   <- 20
toeplitz(c(1, poly(rho, t-1, raw=TRUE)))
```

Although the output of this code does, indeed, produce the matrix of interest, I get the feeling that there's probably a better way of doing it.

Can this code snippet be improved - in the sense that there is a more elegant, more standard, more correct, or more efficient way of creating the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `poly` is probably too much trouble. You can just calculate the polynomial yourself with `rho^seq.int(0, t-1)`. Altogether that gives

```
toeplitz(rho^seq.int(0, t-1))
```